# HDINSIGHT hive, MSCK REPAIR TABLE table_name throwing error

Tags: hive, hadoop-partitioning

i have an external partitioned table named employee with partition(year,month,day), everyday a new file come and seat at the particular day location call for today's date it will be at 2016/10/13.

```
TABLE SCHEMA:
create External table employee(EMPID Int,FirstName String,.....)
partitioned by (year string,month string,day string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' LOCATION '/.../emp';
```

so everyday we need to run command which is working fine as

```
ALTER TABLE employee ADD IF NOT EXISTS PARTITION (year=2016,month=10,day=14) LOCATION '/.../emp/2016/10/14';
```

but once we are trying with below command because we don't want to execute the above alter table command manually, it throws below Error

```
hive> MSCK REPAIR TABLE employee;
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask
```

Note:

```
hive> MSCK TABLE employee; //this show me that a partition has not added in the table
OK
Partitions not in metastore: employee:2016/10/14
Time taken: 1.066 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

please help me as i stuck with this. do we have any workaround for this type of situation?

Comment: I got a workaround solution for my problem, which is if the partition name will be like 'year=2016/month=10/day=13' then we can use below command and it is working...
    set hive.msck.path.validation=ignore;
    MSCK REPAIR TABLE table_name;

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I got a workaround solution for my problem which is, if the table static partition name is like 'year=2016/month=10/day=13' then we can use below command and it is working...

```
set hive.msck.path.validation=ignore;
MSCK REPAIR TABLE table_name;
```

Comment: If you have a large number of partitions you might need to set hive.msck.repair.batch.size.

When there is a large number of untracked partitions, there is a provision to run MSCK REPAIR TABLE batch-wise to avoid OOME (Out of Memory Error).

y giving the configured batch size for the property hive.msck.repair.batch.size it can run in the batches internally. T

the default value of the property is 0, it means it will execute all the partitions at once.