# Athena not adding partitions after msck repair table

Tags: hive, amazon-athena

I have a Firehose that stores data in S3 in the default directory structure:
`YY/MM/DD/HH` and a table in Athena with these columns defined as partitions:

year: string, month: string, day: string, hour: string

after running

```sql
msck repair table clicks
```

I only receive:

```
Partitions not in metastore:    clicks:2017/08/26/10
```

I can add these partitions manually and everything works however, I was wondering why msck repair does not add these partitions automatically and update the metastore?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hive: Partitioning by part of integer column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42950331/hive-partitioning-by-part-of-integer-column)

Comment: Possible duplicate of  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42785633/create-table-partition-in-hive-for-year-month-and-day/42786102#42786102

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz my issue is after running msck repair new partitions are not added automatically, like the posts above show

Comment: ... and like my answers show, only a specific directory naming convention, which you are not using,  is supported

Comment: thanks Ill add year, month , day , hour specifically in my directories

Comment: for to work MSCK your table static partition name should be like 'year=2016/month=10/day=13' then we can use below command and it is working...   
    set hive.msck.path.validation=ignore;
    MSCK REPAIR TABLE table_name;
for more details pls check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40043986/hdinsight-hive-msck-repair-table-table-name-throwing-error/40100053#40100053

Answer (score 7):

To use Athena `MSCK REPAIR` with S3 you need to use key-value pairs as path prefix:

```
clicks/year=2017/month=08/day=26/hour=10/
```

instead of: `clicks/2017/08/26/10/`

Alternatively, update the partitions directly in Glue (manually or use a crawler).

Found this here: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=789078

Answer (score 2):

For future reference, aside from the two tips mentioned in this article: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/athena-aws-glue-msck-repair-table/

- Allow glue:BatchCreatePartition in the IAM policy
- Change the S3 path to flat case

You also need to **set the `TableType` [attribute](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-catalog-tables.html) to a non-null value**. In my case, it was `EXTERNAL_TABLE`.